# Issue with text boxes moving when site re-sized

Tags: html, textbox

This question is in relation to my website **www.elitedentalstaffing.com**

Can anyone tell me why the two text boxes above **"Learn More"** and **"Join Our Team"** move when I zoom in, in my browser? I am using **Chrome** but have seen the same thing in **IE**. The strange thing is the text box above **"Request Staffing Support"** does not move when I zoom in and is basically the same as the other two text boxes. I am new to coding so am just not sure what I am doing wrong. Hoping for a simple fix. Worst case scenario I can burn the text into the image but do not want to do that if possible.

Comment: They are not moving when I zoom in on Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set position:absolute property via css to those text boxes or
set it to auto

Comment: The absolute property doesn't do what I need.  I keeps the text box in one place but everything else moves as I zoom in or out.  I want the text boxes to zoom in and out with everything else but not change its position relative to everything else when a zoom occurs.  My issue appears to be based on the text resizing and adding or subtracting a line from the text box as it does so thus changing the size of the text box and due to the way I have coded affecting the position of the other text box below it in the div codes I have created.  Is there any way to fix the box size to a certain size.

Comment: I figured it out.  Just had to set the height property for the boxes